# redirect domain from unsecured to secure http to https

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, iis-7

I used this (web.config) to redirect all my domain from http to https:

```
<rule name="ssl redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

However this wont work for a domain with number at the end:

mydomain7.com

any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved  the issue by adding redirect type and also add additional input:

```
<rule name="ssl redirect" enabled="true"   stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```